# perform actions on a web page from desktop shortcut

Tags: automation, shortcuts, web, script

I'm looking for a way to create windows desktop shortcuts that will open a web page and execute a javascript function in that page. The page is a form for filling attendance hours with a function to set the current time (bound to a button). So instead of opening the page and clicking the button and then submitting, I'd like to have a shortcut that will do all of this.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Auto-Hotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) for this. Almost full automation available - and definitely can do for your case.

Comment: well, yeah, i know AH. but i was hoping for something more customized for the web. would hate to do that by automating keys and clicks.